# Get standard error of exponentiated coefficient in cox regression

Tags: r, variance, survival, cox-model

When I run coxph, R supplies me with the coefficients, exponentiated coefficient, and standard error. The standard error is for the regression coefficient, $\beta$. How can I get the standard error of the exponentiaed regression coefficient, $exp(\beta)$?

R code:

```
library("survival")
data("lung") #From the survival package
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
summary(res.cox)
```

Which gives me (sorry for the horrible formatting):

> Call:
>     coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
>
> n= 228, number of events= 165
>
> coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)
>   sex -0.5310    0.5880   0.1672 -3.176  0.00149 **

se(coef) is giving me the standard error of "sex". I would like the standard error of exp("sex").

I can find the variance using the delta method, but can R give me the results without doing the calculations myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it manually by calculating $se(sex) \cdot \exp(sex)=0.1672 \cdot 0.5880=.0983136$ since the derivative of $\exp{}$ is $\exp{}$ itself, or like this using svycontrast() in the survey package:

```
library("survival")
library("survey")
data("lung") #From the survival package
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
summary(res.cox)
svycontrast(res.cox, quote(exp(sex)))
```

which yields

```
         nlcon     SE
contrast 0.588 0.0983
```